$C_{c}^{\infty}$ functions is $C^{\infty}_{c}$ when restricted to a line

Given a $C_{c}^{\infty}$ function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$. Given any $u, x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, is $g: t\mapsto f(x_{0}+tu)$ also in $C_{c}^{\infty}$?

I think this is true as we can take basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to encompass the vector $u$, and then any order of derivatives for $g$ is just taking that order of derivatives for $f$ in the direction of $u$ in some sense. However, I'm not sure if formally this would work or not.
This is related to Method of Rotation in Harmonic analysis, where we need to restrict some function to a line.

Yes, chain rule.

Let $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the $C^\infty$-map given by $h(t) = x_0 + tu$. Then $g = f \circ h$. Since $f$ and $h$ are both $C^\infty$, so is $g$. Since $f$ is compactly supported, so is $g$.
